# pdflatex not found on pandoc

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

im trying to convert a MarkDown file to pdf using pandoc. I have installed MikTex on my Windows PC but using the "code"

```
pandoc sample1.md -o sample1.pdf
```

pandoc responds:

```
pdflatex not found. Please select a different --pdf-engine or install pdflatex
```

I tried using the `--pdf-engine=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\pdftex` and also the `--pdf-engine=miktex` command.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If specifying a path, you must give the one to the `pdflatex` binary, not `pdftex`. Using `--pdf-engine=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\pdflatex` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much! This + restart of the PC helped me out :D classic